# What is the specific heat capacity of interstellar clouds?

Tags: interstellar-medium, heat

Star forming [molecular clouds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_cloud) and especially [Bok globules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bok_globule) are low temperature $\sim 10 $ K environments with density on the order of $10^{-18}$ kg/m$^3$, mostly hydrogen with about 1% dust. What is their heat capacity?

I have tried to find good data for low-temperature heat capacities for hydrogen (which would be nice to have anyway), but most experiments also use dense hydrogen rather than the by-Earth-standard very low-pressure molecular gas of the clouds. Are there any decent estimates of how much a given increase in energy increases the cloud temperature? Or should one just use the ideal gas [approximation for a diatomic gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_heat_capacity#Rotational_modes_of_a_diatomic_molecule) and assume $C_v\approx (5/2)R$ per mole?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At such low temperatures ($\sim10\,\mathrm{K}$), the rotational and vibrational degrees-of-freedom of the hydrogen molecule [freeze out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molar_heat_capacity#Frozen_and_active_degrees_of_freedom) and it acts like a monatomic ideal gas with only translational degrees of freedom, so $C_v\sim (3/2)R$ per mole is probably a better estimate.

The "freeze out" is because rotational and vibrational states are quantized, so when $kT << \hbar\omega$, thermally driven transitions become almost impossible.  (Understanding the temperature dependence of the specific heat of molecular hydrogen was a [major challenge and then success](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00407-009-0053-2) of early quantum mechanics.
) For hydrogen molecules, the fundamental vibration mode is [4161 $\mathrm{cm^{-1}}$ = 0.52 eV](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6390), corresponding to a temperature of about 6000 K.  This is why vibrational modes can be ignored at room temperature and $C_v\sim (5/2)R$.
The energy difference between the lowest energy rotational states ([ortho- and para-hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_isomers_of_hydrogen#Allowed_rotational_energy_levels)) is [0.34 kcal/mol](https://doi.org/10.1515/zna-1979-0206) =14.7 meV, corresponds to a temperature of 171 K, however, so in equilibrium at 10 K the rotational modes are also mostly inaccessible and the hydrogen gas will be all parahydrogen and $C_v\sim (3/2)R$.

I don't think the dust contributes much to the total heat capacity, but it is [likely important](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.molap.2017.11.001) for catalyzing transitions to reach equilibrium.